# substract column using a only a single row in other column

Tags: awk

I have a file like

```
111  222  50.00

555  555

55    20
```

I want to subtract `$2` from first row of `$3` for all value in `$2`. 
I have tried using `awk '{print $2-$3}'` but I can only get subtraction for a single row of `$2` column so how can I subtract whole `$2` using a value of 1st row `$3` column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grep . file|awk '{NR==1&&a=$3};{print $2-a}'
```

Are you after something like that?